# IOS: Get current date/time with specific (non-localized) format

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, string-formatting, nsdateformatter

I want to get the current date/time in a very specific format like this:

> 2013-11-24_18_12_88

However, using the following code:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];   
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd_hh_mm_ss"];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

I get this date string instead:

> 2013-11-24_18:12:88

How can I force the dateFormatter to **not** delete the "_" in my date format and replace them with ":"?

Comment: Try putting quotes around them (`'_'`).  Plus that should be `HH` shouldn't it?

Comment: @Droppy: Awesome, that works! Can you explain, why? Also, please put it in an answer, so I can accept it...

Comment: I think you can replace ':' by '_' after getting result "2013-11-24_18:12:88"

Comment: @JanRüegg Actually I'm not entirely sure why.  Are you sure it wasn't just changing the `HH` that solved it?

Comment: @Droppy: You're right, it actually is the HH instead of hh that solved the issue :D

Comment: So if you put that into an answer, I can accept that...

Comment: @keyurbhalodiya: That would not work, since depending on the system, sometimes I was also getting "2013-11-24_18/12/88"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `HH` instead of `hh` in the date formatting specifier:

```
@"yyyy-MM-dd_HH_mm_ss"
             ^^
```